# MongoDB how to choose data from database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am building a query, and I can request and post all data from the database. But now I need to request 1 item from the database. But I can't seem to make it work.

```
// Get translations
router.get('/', (req, res, next)=>{
    Translations.find(function(err,translations){
        res.json(translations);
    })
});
```

That WORKS FINE!

```
// Get specific translations
router.get('/:dataName', (req, res, next)=>{
    Translations.find({attributes: req.params.dataName}, function(err,translations){
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            res.json(translations);
        }

    })
});
```

The data I need to find is in db contactlist->translations and is called data-name.

```
[
  {
    _id: "5a55d8aadae5790530b9b6dc",
    attributes:
    {
      data-name: "h1_welcome_text",
      _id: "5a55d8aadae5790530b9b6dd",
      classes: [
        "welcome_text",
        "header"
      ]
    },
    __v: 0,
    text: [
    {
      language: "nl",
      text: "Welkom op onze applicatie",
      _id: "5a55d8aadae5790530b9b6df"
    },
    {
      language: "eng",
      text: "Welcome to our application",
      _id: "5a55d8aadae5790530b9b6de"
    }]
  },
```

I need to just search for the "data-name".

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with :

```
Translations.find({'attributes.data-name': req.params.dataName}, cb)
```

doc : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#query-fields-of-an-embedded-document

Comment: it says cb is not defined

Comment: Replace cb with your callback

Comment: Now I just need to figure out how i can get the info i get from that query and put the data in a button.